# Remove only half of specific adjacent duplicates in python list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a tool which is outputting some data . It is known that whenever '10' comes in the data it is added with extra '10' I.e new data becomes ... '10', '10', .  Sometimes there can be 4 '10' in consecutive series which means that there is actually 2 '10'.

While reading the data I am trying to remove the duplicates . Till now I have learnt how to remove duplicates if only two adjacent duplicates are found but at the same time if even number of duplicates are found , I want to return half of the duplicates .

```
x = [ '10', '10', '00', 'DF', '20' ,'10' ,'10' ,'10' ,'10', ....]
```

Expected output

```
[ '10', '00' , 'DF', ' 20', ' 10', '10' ..]
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: @ Henry 28 Using list comprehension . y= [ x[I] for I in ange (Len(x)) if (I==0) or ( x[i-1] != x[I]) or ( x[I] != '10')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use `groupby()` from `itertools`:

```
X= [ '10', '10', '00', 'DF', '20' ,'10' ,'10' ,'10' ,'10']

from itertools import groupby

result = []
for k, g in groupby(X) :
    group = list(g)
    if k == '10' :
        result.extend(group[:(len(group)+1)/2])
    else :
        result.extend(group)
print result
```

gives:

```
['10', '00', 'DF', '20', '10', '10']
```

Comment: @ lenik I am new to this group by function . I will check it and come back .

Comment: @Poka try `for k, g in groupby(X) : print k, list(g)` -- this will give you a better understanding what this function does.

Comment: @ lenik I have also some other consecutive data like '00','00'… the previous solution is replacing them also . But I want only to reduce '10'

Comment: @Poka not a problem, check the updated answer in about 15 sec =)

Comment: @ lenik It workd!  Hope I have not missed any other criteria related to this adjacent duplicates .

Comment: @Poka glad to hear that! if you find any other criteria, just leave a comment here and I'll amend the solution

Answer (score 0):

A pure python approach

```
ls = []
dupe = True
for item in x:
    if ls and ls[-1] == item and dupe:
        dupe = False
        continue
    dupe = True
    ls.append(item)

['10', '00', 'DF', '20', '10', '10']
```